# Any Drug working as " Anti Anaesthetic "?

Tags: anesthesia, sedative-sedation

i wanted to know is there any drug to defuse the effects of anaestethics and sedatives? And not being a prescribed drug , or meant for specific diseases?
By the way I have Hashimoto, so it shouldn't Interfere with my disease ,
Thanx